# UIButton doesn't appear on iOS Today Widget

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, widget

I am creating a today extension for my app, but there are some errors that I can't quite understand:

First: 
Everything is Ok on the storyboard, but the button doesn't appear on the widget.

Second: When the tableview has more than one cell, the last cell gets cut.

Third: CellForRow is called, but don't change anything on the cell (Label is still "Label").

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jp31V.png

Here's my Widget code:

```
@implementation TodayViewController{

    NSMutableArray *listaFavoritos;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.widgetTableView.delegate = self;
    self.widgetTableView.dataSource = self;

    [self updateTableView];

    self.preferredContentSize = self.widgetTableView.frame.size;
}

- (void)widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NCUpdateResult))completionHandler {
    // Perform any setup necessary in order to update the view.

    // If an error is encountered, use NCUpdateResultFailed
    // If there's no update required, use NCUpdateResultNoData
    // If there's an update, use NCUpdateResultNewData

    completionHandler(NCUpdateResultNewData);
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(userDefaultsDidChange:)
                                                     name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification
                                                   object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)userDefaultsDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self updateTableView];
}

- (void)updateTableView {
    listaFavoritos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //listaFavoritos = [[self readArrayWithCustomObjFromUserDefaults:@"listaFavs"] mutableCopy];
    [listaFavoritos addObject:@"test1"];
    [listaFavoritos addObject:@"test2"];
    NSLog(@"%@", listaFavoritos);
}

-(NSArray *)readArrayWithCustomObjFromUserDefaults:(NSString*)keyName
{
    NSUserDefaults *sharedDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.kazoowa.timers"];
    NSData *data = [sharedDefaults objectForKey:keyName];
    NSArray *myArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
    [sharedDefaults synchronize];
    return myArray;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [listaFavoritos count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    WidgetTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"WidgetCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell.nomeTimer.text = [listaFavoritos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    NSLog(@"CellForRow");

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)For your second problem, your cellIdentifier in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath will be "static" like this :

```
static NSString *cellName = @"WidgetCell";
WidgetTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellName forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

2)this condition will be never execute because it's never nil :

```
if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell.nomeTimer.text = [listaFavoritos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
```

replace it by this :

```
if (cell != nil)
    {
        cell.nomeTimer.text = [listaFavoritos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
```

3)Please use Pragma Mark for separate properly your code like below:

```
   #pragma mark-UITableViewDataSource

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
    return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        return [listaFavoritos count];
    }

    #pragma mark-UITableViewDelegate

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        WidgetTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"WidgetCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell.nomeTimer.text = [listaFavoritos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }

        NSLog(@"CellForRow");

        return cell;
    }
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I could not make the cell static. I got this error: "Inicializer Element in not a Compile-Time constant". Thank you!

Comment: The method tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: will return an UITableViewCell not a WidgetTableViewCell (What is this, subclass?) like you do. I don't know if is your problem, but this code is not pretty clear.

Comment: cell.textLabel.text = @"text" is an common way for change textLabel. It's very hard for Debug your code because you use subclass when it's not necessary. Another Example, is when you use listaFavoristos without property and Category.

Comment: WidgetTableViewCell is a subclass, I just created that because I want to create a custom button inside the cell and I don't know how to do that without the subclass. 

when I use listaFavoritos without Category? What's a Category?

I'm sorry, I'm new on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellName = @"WidgetCell";


    WidgetTableViewCell *cell = (WidgetTableViewCell *)[theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellName];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[WidgetTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellName];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [listaFavoritos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];;

    return cell;
}
```